# Java, Android, thread safe unique operation with respect to memory

Tags: java, android, concurrency, singleton

In my application, I need to perform some long running task. I need it to be accessible from different program components with their own independent lifecycle (in particular from Activities, and Service components of Android application), and from different threads as well. At the same time, I don't need this operation to be performed too often, therefore I don't want to pollute into memory. So I developed some kind of auto closeable Singleton, but I'm not sure if I made it right, and there won't be any problem with my solution. So I'm looking for some expertise. The solution looks like this:

```
public class UniqueOperation {

    private static volatile UniqueOperation instance = null;
    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    private volatile int connections;
    private volatile boolean isRunning;

    private UniqueOperation() {}

    public static UniqueOperation getInstance() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (instance == null) {
               instance = new UniqueOperation();
            }
            instance.connections++;
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void requestWork() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (isRunning) {
                return;
            } else {
                isRunning = true;
            }
        }

        doWork();

        synchronized (lock) {
            isRunning = false;
            if (connections < 1) {
                instance = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void doWork() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
       synchronized (lock) {
           return isRunning;
       }
    }

    public void close() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            connections--;
            if (connections < 1 && !isRunning) {
                instance = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any component which got instance supposed to call `close()` once the component has no need in instance anymore.

My priorities are uniqueness, thread safe and memory usage.

Comment: This belongs on the Code Review stack exchange better. See [ask] and [mcve] for details on how to craft a good question. Even so, who's gonna call this? What are things you are worried about - performance, thread safety etc?

Comment: Access to all the variables are properly synchronized by `synchronized` blocks, so I'd say that all the `volatile` declarations are excessive